# Using async await and dynamic import statements with Babel and Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

When using `async await`, webpack guide recommends using `babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`.
https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

I ran into an error and figured that's not the only plugin required.  Babel docs recommends using `babel-polyfill`. So, I just want to confirm if this plugin handles both the `async await` and `dynamic imports` for older browsers? Do I need to add `babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` as well?

Sorry if the question seems naive, but from word polyfill it seems it should cover all of the cases for older browsers. Awaiting inputs!

Answer (score 0):

`syntax-dynamic-import` is inserted to allow you to use `import(/path/to/file)` (dynamic import), this has nothing to do with async await.

For async await you will need [`async to generators`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator/).

When you add `babel-polyfill` it adds everything necessary. You must also add the browser versions you want to support on the babel-env options.

Comment: Ok. So why has then  babel released `syntax-dynamic-import` plugin ? They should have thought of something.